# Migrating from Visual Studio 2008 to 2013 with big solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013, migrate

I try to migrate Visual Studio 2008 projects to Visual Studio 2013 from a big solution (consists of 100+ projects). When I open the projects with VS 2013, it opens its "One way upgrade" tool and I click upgrade. But for some projects the program goes unresponsive. It only creates a default .vcxproj file but not the fully converted project.It is a dummy project file and when it is opened nothing appears in project explorer.
The solution conversion stops especially in these projects and freeze occurs. When I try to convert this projects individually, it sometimes converts to 2013 project, in some projects it does not. When I uncheck projects that causes problem, conversion proceeds some more but freeze again in another project.
I checked Microsoft's pages and other conversion problems here, nothing is wrong about framework versions of my project, I also did not encountered with file copy replace when converting project.
For sample :
This is the header of my project that does not convert and causes VS 2013 to freeze in converting process :

```
<VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="9,00"
    Name="GlobalDeployment"
    ProjectGUID="{AC9CBDA0-2504-4D84-9361-E2F112F56A29}"
    RootNamespace="GlobalDeployment"
    Keyword="MakeFileProj"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="196613"
    >
And this is the one which has no problem in converting :

<VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="9,00"
    Name="CommonUtilities"
    ProjectGUID="{1FB295FC-DE93-42D1-8AC8-6D51DF017C74}"
    RootNamespace="CommonUtility"
    Keyword="Qt4VSv1.0"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="196613"
    >
```

I also checked qt vs addin, but I converted qt projects before with no problem.
I checked paths declared in project file. They are correct.
So what can be the source of this freezing problem?
Thanks

Comment: The project that doesn't convert has Version="9.00" (with a period decimal inidator). The project that does convert has Verison="9,00" (with a comma decimal indicator). Is that a typo or do they genuinely use different decimal markers?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo from my trial in changing version of my project to see its effects on migration. Actually it makes no difference, VS 13 still freezes in migration process

Comment: I observed that the conversion freezing place is somehow random, so it may be a problem about VS 2013 not project files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mainly caused by using "User Macros" that contains '.' characters.
I had user macros like "root.dir" in my projects in VS2008 and VS2013 just does not accept defining user macros like that. When I replaced user macros used in .vcproj file with words not containing '.' character, usually the process of migration is completed.
If this does not solve your problem, then try to change .vsprops files of your project that contains '.' character in their user macros. If you used user macros contains dots in your .vsprops file then VS2013 migrator changes it to a dummy .prop file. Sometimes it cannot generate prop file and migration freezes.
So when a solution of many projects is tried to be converted, then if some of projects contains user macros that is not allowed in VS2013 in some place the migration freezes.

Comment: VS2013 also does not accept user macros entered from property window

Comment: Also you can remove vsprops files that is not accepted by VS 2013 and continue to migration.